# Friendship system

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

`users`:

- user_id
- user_name
- ...

`friends`:

- user_id (user who sent friend request)
- friend_id (user who received a friend request)
- confirmed (1 = friends, 0 = friend request)

I want each user to be able to see their friends and friend requests. I have problem with displaying friends usernames. I made it work, but it's a poor solution and I want to solve this problem using only one query (if possible).

I tried:

```
    $sql = "SELECT friends.friend_id, friends.user_id, users.user_name FROM friends
            INNER JOIN users ON friends.user_id = users.user_id
            WHERE friends.user_id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . " AND confirmed = 1
            OR friends.friend_id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . " AND confirmed = 1;";
```

My problem is that it will show `user_name` of users that have `user_id` same as `user_id` in friends table. My query needs to check if `user_id` is the same as the `$_SESSION['user_id']`, and if it's the same then it must return `user_name` of the user that has the `user_id` the same as `friend_id` in `friends` table.

Comment: Is there a limit on the friends the user can have?

Comment: _"I'm new to databases"_ Good, now is the time to avoid learning bad habits. Don't build queries with string concatenation. Instead use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: @Toleo No there is no limit.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thank you! Will fix this problem :) Can you help me with my primary problem too?

Comment: @MaticJan So as I understood, You want to select all the `user`'s confirmed friends And the unconfirmed friends, correct?

Comment: @Toleo In this case I only need to select users confirmed friends and display their user_name which can be found in users table

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @adpro I'm aware of this problem and my question is not related to this, but thanks anyway, will fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulate your SQL query in the following way,

```
$sql = "SELECT 
    " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . " as user_id, 
    IF(u2.user_id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ", u1.user_id, f.friend_id) as friend_id, 
    IF(f.user_id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ", u2.user_name, u1.user_name) as friend_username
FROM users as u1
INNER JOIN friends as f
ON u1.user_id = f.user_id
INNER JOIN users as u2
ON f.friend_id = u2.user_id
WHERE (f.user_id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . " OR f.friend_id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ") AND f.confirmed = 1";
```

Here's the live demo: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e10252/7**

---

**Sidenote:** Learn about [**prepared statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your query is susceptible to SQL injection attack. Also see [**how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: See about sql injection

Comment: @Strawberry At this point it's unclear which API(MySQLi or PDO) OP is using, so added a sidenote there.

Comment: Hey I tried this solution, but its not working. In your example I need to output: ABC and XYZ

Comment: @MaticJan I have updated my answer, please see **Update(1)** section of my answer. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Folks, I've cleaned up unnecessary/intermediate code and kept the final working code as the solution code.